# Qt - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault, qpixmap

I've searched high and low for the answer and I know my fault (exit code: -1073741819) is caused by a general access violation but cannot figure out how my code is generating this error.

To make things even more strange, this program compiled and ran less than a week ago, albeit with a few bugs. I didn't change any code, opened it up today to have one quick look through my code as I'm being interviewed on it tomorrow, and this error pops up.

The SIGSEGV occurs on Line 23 of the item.cpp class, where `return ItemPicture` is located.

Sorry for the wall of code, but it's better to include everything. Thanks in advance!

Here is the full code for the program:

**inventory.h**

```
#ifndef INVENTORY_H
#define INVENTORY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "item.h"

using namespace std;

class Inventory
{
private:
    vector<Item> inventory;
    vector<string> inventoryItems;
public:
    Inventory();
    void deleteItem(int i);
    Item *getItem(int i);
    bool hasItem(int i);
    void addItem(Item *inItem);
    int getSize();
    bool hasString(string inString);
};

#endif // INVENTORY_H
```

**inventory.cpp**

```
#include "inventory.h"
#include "item.h"

using namespace std;

Inventory::Inventory()
{
}

void Inventory::addItem(Item *inItem)
{
    inventory.push_back(*inItem);
    inventoryItems.push_back(inItem->getDescription());
}

void Inventory::deleteItem(int i)
{
    inventory.erase(inventory.begin()+i);
}

bool Inventory::hasItem(int i){
    if(inventory.size() > i){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

Item* Inventory::getItem(int i){
    return &inventory[i];
}

int Inventory::getSize(){
    return inventory.size();
}

bool Inventory::hasString(string inString){
    if(std::find(inventoryItems.begin(), inventoryItems.end(), inString) != inventoryItems.end()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**item.h**

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H
#include<QMainWindow>
using namespace std;

class Item
{
public:
    Item(string inDescription, QPixmap *pic, int value);
    int getValue();
    void setValue(int inValue);
    string getDescription();
    QPixmap getPic();
    void setPic(QPixmap pic);

private:
    QPixmap itemPicture;
    int value;
    string description;
};

#endif // ITEM_H
```

**item.cpp**

```
#include "item.h"

Item::Item(string inDescription, QPixmap *pic, int inValue){
    itemPicture = *pic;
    value = inValue;
    description = inDescription;
}

int Item::getValue(){
    return value;
}

void Item::setValue(int inValue){
    value = inValue;
}

string Item::getDescription(){
    return description;
}


QPixmap Item::getPic(){
    return itemPicture; //ERROR OCCURS HERE
}

void Item::setPic(QPixmap inPic){
    itemPicture = inPic;
}
```

**room.h**

```
#ifndef ROOM_H
#define ROOM_H
#include<QMainWindow>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "item.h"

using namespace std;
using std::vector;

class Room
{
private:
    string description;
    int roomNum;
    map<string, Room*> exits;
    vector <Item> itemsInRoom;
    QPixmap roomImage;
    bool locked;

public:
    Room(int roomNum, string description, QPixmap *pic);
    void setExits(Room *north = NULL, Room *east = NULL, Room *south = NULL, Room *west = NULL);
    void setImage(QPixmap *pic);
    QPixmap getImage();
    string shortDescription();
    string longDescription();
    Room *nextRoom(string direction);
    Item *getItem(int i);
    void deleteItem(int i);
    bool hasItem(int i);
    void addItem(Item*inItem);
    int getRoomNum();
    int getSize();
    bool getLocked();
    void setLocked(bool value);
};

#endif // ROOM_H
```

**room.cpp**

```
#include "room.h"
#include "inventory.h"
#include <QPixmap>

Room::Room(int roomNum, string description, QPixmap *pic) {
    this->description = description;
    this->roomImage = *pic;
    this->roomNum = roomNum;

    if(roomNum == 7){
        locked = true;
    }else{
        locked = false;
    }
}

void Room::setExits(Room *north, Room *east, Room *south, Room *west) {
    if (north != NULL)
        exits["north"] = north;
    if (east != NULL)
        exits["east"] = east;
    if (south != NULL)
        exits["south"] = south;
    if (west != NULL)
        exits["west"] = west;
}

string Room::shortDescription() {
    return description;
}

string Room::longDescription() {
    if(itemsInRoom.size()>0)
        return "You are in " + description+". There may be items in this room that could help you..";
    else{
        return "You are in " + description;
    }
}

bool Room::hasItem(int i){
    if(itemsInRoom.size() > i){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Room::addItem(Item *inItem) {
    itemsInRoom.push_back(*inItem);
}

void Room::deleteItem(int i) {
    itemsInRoom.erase(itemsInRoom.begin()+i);
}

Item* Room::getItem(int i){
    return &itemsInRoom[i];
}

int Room::getRoomNum(){
    return roomNum;
}

void Room::setImage(QPixmap *pic){
   roomImage = *pic;
}

QPixmap Room::getImage(){
  return roomImage;
}

int Room::getSize(){
  return itemsInRoom.size();
}

Room* Room::nextRoom(string direction) {
    map<string, Room*>::iterator next = exits.find(direction);
    if (next == exits.end())
        return NULL;
    return next->second;
}

bool Room::getLocked()
{
    return locked;
}

void Room::setLocked(bool value)
{
    locked = value;
}
```

**rungame.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include "room.h"
#include "item.h"
#include "inventory.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void createRooms();
    void play();
    void display();
    void setItems();
    void takeItems(int i);
    void dropItems(int i);
    void displayInventory();
    void setVisibleItems();
    Room *lockedRoom;

private slots:
    void on_northButton_clicked();
    void on_eastButton_clicked();
    void on_westButton_clicked();
    void on_southButton_clicked();
    void on_mapButton_clicked();
    void on_inventDropButton1_clicked();
    void on_inventDropButton2_clicked();
    void on_inventDropButton3_clicked();
    void setDirectionButtonsOn();
    void on_roomTakeButton1_clicked();
    void on_roomTakeButton2_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Room *startingRoom, *currentRoom, *nextRoom;
    Inventory *inventory;
    Item *currentItem;
    Item *equippedItem;
    QPixmap roomImage;
    string direction;
    bool b;
    void setDirectionButtons(bool inState);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**rungame.cpp**

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "rungame.h"
#include "inventory.h"
#include "room.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.play();

    return a.exec();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->imgLabel->updatesEnabled();
    inventory = new Inventory();
    ui->consoleOut->setReadOnly(true);
    setItems();
    createRooms();
    setVisibleItems();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::createRooms()
{
    Room *cell, *solitaryHall, *chrisCell, *showerHall, *canteenHall, *canteen, *guardOffice,
            *visitRoom, *yard, *parkingLot, *runningTrack, *entrance, *shower;

    cell = new Room(1, "your cell", new QPixmap(":/img/img/cell.png"));
        cell->addItem(new Item("Shank", new QPixmap(":/img/img/shank.png"), 1));
        cell->addItem(new Item("Soap", new QPixmap(":/img/img/soap.png"), 2));
    solitaryHall = new Room(2, "the solitary confinement hall", new QPixmap(":/img/img/solitaryhall.png"));
    chrisCell = new Room(3, "Chris' cell", new QPixmap(":/img/img/chriscell.png"));
    showerHall = new Room(4, "the shower hall", new QPixmap(":/img/img/showerhall.png"));
    canteenHall = new Room(5, "the canteen Hall", new QPixmap(":/img/img/canteenhall.png"));
    canteen = new Room(6, "the canteen", new QPixmap(":/img/img/canteen.png"));
        canteen->addItem(new Item("Standard Prison Meal", new QPixmap(":/img/img/meal.png"), 4));
        canteen->addItem(new Item("Fork", new QPixmap(":/img/img/fork.png"), 5));
    guardOffice = new Room(7, "the guards office", new QPixmap(":/img/img/guardoffice.png"));
        guardOffice->addItem(new Item("Guard Uniform", new QPixmap(":/img/img/uniform.png"),6));
    visitRoom = new Room(8, "the visitors Room", new QPixmap(":/img/img/visitroom.png"));
    yard = new Room(9, "the yard", new QPixmap(":/img/img/yard.png"));
    parkingLot = new Room(10, "Parking Lot", new QPixmap(":/img/img/parkinglot.png"));
    runningTrack = new Room(11, "Running Track", new QPixmap(":/img/img/runningTrack.png"));
    entrance = new Room(12, "Prison Entrance", new QPixmap(":/img/img/entrance.png"));
    shower = new Room(13, "Showers", new QPixmap(":/img/img/shower.png"));

    //NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
    cell->setExits(solitaryHall, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    solitaryHall->setExits(chrisCell, showerHall, cell, NULL);
    chrisCell->setExits(NULL, NULL, solitaryHall, NULL);
    showerHall->setExits(shower, canteenHall, NULL, solitaryHall);
    canteenHall->setExits(canteen, NULL, guardOffice, showerHall);
    canteen->setExits(NULL, NULL, canteenHall, NULL);
    guardOffice->setExits(canteenHall, visitRoom, NULL, NULL);
    visitRoom->setExits(NULL, yard, NULL, guardOffice);
    yard->setExits(runningTrack, parkingLot, entrance, visitRoom);
    shower->setExits(NULL, NULL, showerHall, NULL);

    startingRoom = cell;
    currentRoom = cell;
    lockedRoom = guardOffice;
    roomImage = currentRoom->getImage();
    ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(roomImage);
}

void MainWindow::play()
{
    ui->consoleOut->append("You are sitting at your desk reading a book. The lights go"
                            " out and you hear your cell door unbolt. It starts to creak"
                            " open. Will you leave?");
    ui->consoleOut->append("");
}

void MainWindow::takeItems(int i)
{
    if(inventory->getSize() < 3){
        switch(i){
        case 0: ui->inventSlot1->setVisible(false); ui->roomTakeButton1->setVisible(false); break;
        case 1: ui->inventSlot2->setVisible(false); ui->roomTakeButton2->setVisible(false); break;
        }

        inventory->addItem(currentRoom->getItem(i));
        ui->consoleOut->append(QString::fromStdString("You have taken the: " + currentRoom->getItem(i)->getDescription()));
        currentRoom->deleteItem(i);
        displayInventory();
    }else{
        ui->consoleOut->append("Inventory full. Please drop an item.");
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
    }
    setItems();
}

void MainWindow::dropItems(int i)
{
    if(inventory->getSize() > 0){
        switch(i){
        case 0: ui->inventSlot1->setVisible(true); ui->inventDropButton1->setVisible(true); break;
        case 1: ui->inventSlot2->setVisible(true); ui->inventDropButton2->setVisible(true); break;
        }
        currentRoom->addItem(inventory->getItem(i));
        ui->consoleOut->append(QString::fromStdString("You have dropped the: " + inventory->getItem(i)->getDescription()));
        if(currentRoom->getRoomNum()==13){
            ui->consoleOut->append("You are lucky nobody is around!");
        }
        inventory->deleteItem(i);
        displayInventory();
    }
}

void MainWindow::setVisibleItems()
{
    ui->roomTakeButton1->setVisible(true);
    ui->roomTakeButton2->setVisible(true);
    ui->roomSlot1->setVisible(true);
    ui->roomSlot2->setVisible(true);
    ui->inventSlot1->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventSlot2->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventSlot3->setVisible(false);
    ui->imgLabel->setVisible(true);
}

void MainWindow::display()
{
    setDirectionButtons(true);
    b = true;
    ui->consoleOut->append(QString::fromStdString("Go " + direction));
    ui->consoleOut->append("");
    nextRoom = currentRoom->nextRoom(direction);

    if(currentRoom->getRoomNum()==5){
        if(inventory->hasString("Fork")){
            lockedRoom->setLocked(false);
        }
    }

    if(currentRoom->getRoomNum()==5 && inventory->hasString("Fork")){
        ui->consoleOut->append("You use the fork in your inventory to pick the lock.");
    }

    if(nextRoom == NULL){
        ui->consoleOut->append("You cannot go that way.");
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
    }else if(nextRoom->getLocked()){
        ui->consoleOut->append("This door is locked. Look around for something to help open it, or pick the lock!");
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
    }else{
        currentRoom = nextRoom;
        ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(currentRoom->getImage());
        ui->imgLabel->update();
        ui->consoleOut->append(QString::fromStdString(currentRoom->longDescription()));
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
    }

    if(currentRoom->getRoomNum() == 13 && inventory->hasString("Soap")){
        ui->consoleOut->append("You have Soap in your inventory, be careful not to drop it!");
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
    }

    if(currentRoom->getRoomNum() == 9){
        ui->consoleOut->append("You look around for possible escape methods. ");
        ui->consoleOut->append("North) You can try and jump the chain fence surrounding the running track ");
        ui->consoleOut->append("East) Go into the parking lot and look for a car to hide in ");
        ui->consoleOut->append("South) Walk directly past the guards (Hint: if you have a uniform they might not notice)");
    }

    if(currentRoom->getRoomNum() == 10){
        ui->consoleOut->append("You climb into the back of a delivery truck unnoticed."
                               "The driver starts his engine and drives away. You have escaped!");
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
        ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/parkinglot.png"));
        setVisibleItems();
        setDirectionButtons(false);
    }else if(currentRoom->getRoomNum() == 11){
        ui->consoleOut->append("You make a run for the chainlink fence but a guard dog notices you."
                               "The dog catches up and gets a firm grip of your leg. You're going nowhere."
                               "You have failed to escape.");
        ui->consoleOut->append("");
        ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/runningtrack.png"));
        setVisibleItems();
        setDirectionButtons(false);
    }else if(currentRoom->getRoomNum() == 12){
        if(inventory->hasString("Guards Uniform")){
            ui->consoleOut->append("You walk boldly past the guards at the main entrance."
                                   "They are too busy fixing the power to notice you are a prisoner in their uniform. You have escaped!");
            ui->consoleOut->append("");
            setVisibleItems();
            setDirectionButtons(false);
            ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/escape.png"));
        }else{
            ui->consoleOut->append("You try walking past the guards in your prisoner unifrom."
                                   "You are immediately spotted and caught by the guards. You have failed to escape.");
            ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/prisoner.png"));
            setVisibleItems();
            setDirectionButtons(false);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::displayInventory()
{
    int i = 0;
    ui->inventSlot1->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventSlot2->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventSlot3->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventDropButton1->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventDropButton2->setVisible(false);
    ui->inventDropButton3->setVisible(false);

    while(inventory->hasItem(i)){
        switch(i){
        case 0:
            ui->inventSlot1->setPixmap(QPixmap(inventory->getItem(i)->getPic()));
            ui->inventSlot1->setVisible(true);
            ui->inventDropButton1->setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 1:
            ui->inventSlot2->setPixmap(QPixmap(inventory->getItem(i)->getPic()));
            ui->inventSlot2->setVisible(true);
            ui->inventDropButton2->setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            ui->inventSlot3->setPixmap(QPixmap(inventory->getItem(i)->getPic()));
            ui->inventSlot3->setVisible(true);
            ui->inventDropButton3->setVisible(true);
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void MainWindow::setItems()
{
    if(currentRoom->hasItem(0)){
        ui->roomSlot1->setPixmap(currentRoom->getItem(0)->getPic());
        ui->roomSlot1->setVisible(true);
        ui->roomTakeButton1->setVisible(true);
    }else{
        ui->roomSlot1->setVisible(false);
        ui->roomTakeButton1->setVisible(false);
    }

    if(currentRoom->hasItem(1)){
        ui->roomSlot2->setPixmap(currentRoom->getItem(1)->getPic());
        ui->roomSlot2->setVisible(true);
        ui->roomTakeButton2->setVisible(true);
    }else{
        ui->roomSlot2->setVisible(false);
        ui->roomTakeButton2->setVisible(false);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_mapButton_clicked()
{
        int i = currentRoom->getRoomNum();
        switch(i){
            case 1: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map1.png"));break;
            case 2: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map2.png")); break;
            case 3: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map3.png")); break;
            case 4: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map4.png")); break;
            case 5: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map5.png")); break;
            case 6: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map6.png")); break;
            case 7: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map7.png")); break;
            case 8: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map8.png")); break;
            case 9: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map9.png")); break;
            case 10: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map10.png")); break;
            case 11: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map11.png")); break;
            case 12: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map12.png")); break;
            case 13: ui->imgLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/img/img/map13.png")); break;
            }
}

void MainWindow::on_northButton_clicked()
{
    direction = "north";
    display();
}

void MainWindow::on_southButton_clicked()
{
    direction = "south";
    display();
}

void MainWindow::on_eastButton_clicked()
{
    direction = "east";
    display();
}

void MainWindow::on_westButton_clicked()
{
    direction = "west";
    display();
}

void MainWindow::setDirectionButtons(bool inState){
    ui->eastButton->setVisible(inState);
    ui->westButton->setVisible(inState);
    ui->southButton->setVisible(inState);
    ui->northButton->setVisible(inState);

    ui->roomSlot1->setVisible(inState);
    ui->roomSlot2->setVisible(inState);
    ui->roomTakeButton1->setVisible(inState);
    ui->roomTakeButton2->setVisible(inState);


        setItems();


}

void MainWindow::on_roomTakeButton1_clicked()
{
    takeItems(0);
}

void MainWindow::on_roomTakeButton2_clicked()
{
    takeItems(1);
}

void MainWindow::on_inventDropButton1_clicked()
{
    dropItems(0);
}

void MainWindow::on_inventDropButton2_clicked()
{
    dropItems(1);
}

void MainWindow::on_inventDropButton3_clicked()
{
    dropItems(2);
}

void MainWindow::setDirectionButtonsOn()
{
    ui->northButton->setVisible(true);
    ui->eastButton->setVisible(true);
    ui->southButton->setVisible(true);
    ui->westButton->setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Have you actually using printf to print some values? Where are your unit tests? You are not bounds checking arrays. You do not null check values. You specifically do things like add i to begin() on a vector and hope for the best. What I am saying is there are many opportunities to corrupt memory, you have more than I just mentioned. 
One of the joys of userspace programming is the debugging environment. Start with printf - put debug prints in pertinent places and examine the values. Or just dive in with the debugger, this all appears single threaded making you life pretty easy.

Comment: Another tool is to tell someone (it can be a housebrick or a toaster, doesn't matter) how your program works and what it does. That often has the effect of showing up things that were done incorrectly.

Comment: Also, don't drop the soap in the prison shower. Not sure what the interview is for, but be careful with those kinds of jokes in some circumstances.

Comment: If I'm honest, we started programming C++ less than 12 weeks ago, our lecturer gave us the bones of a Zork game and expected us to use Qt to add a GUI to it, I'm not well versed in C++ at all so that's why a lot of the things you mentioned are present.

Our lecturer has an odd sense of humour, he'd enjoy that joke, it also only shows up if you happen to pick up the soap item and then decide to drop it in the shower, "Chris' cell" is also a poke at him, as his name is Chris.

Comment: Nice :) I was thinking job interview as opposed to college work.
 Disclaimer: I don't know Qt at all. The object that is returned on line 23 is a copy (QPixmap) -  I would look around where you additem the 'Item' instance. For instance, what happens if one of the PNG images is not found?  BTW the data never gets freed, this will leak memory rather badly. deleteItem only removes it from the container, it does not delete it.